# How can I update a specific record without SELECT permission?

Tags: mysql

I want to execute something like this:

```
  UPDATE grades SET status="pass" WHERE recno=123;
```

However, I want the user account doing the update to have write-only access to the database which means it does not have SELECT access.  This causes the WHERE clause to fail.

If necessary, I can actually re-write the entire record, but recno is the primary key, which would cause the write to fail.  Is there a way to do

```
INSERT INTO grades (recno,name,status,...) VALUES (123, 'chemistry', 'pass',...)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE <everything>;
```

or is this the wrong approach?  Besides, it's not the general solution to the "update a specific field in a specific record" problem.

Comment: A little more information:  I have an app that writes logs to a remote server. The app will write a new record at the start of the procedure, with a status of "incomplete".  This step will receive an auto-generated recno value back from the Mysql server.  When the process is complete, I want to modify the status field of that record with a new value.  Since anybody could run strings on the application and obtain its login credentials, I need to give that account write-only access to the database.

Comment: What do you mean by 'everybody can run strings on the database'? You grant everybody access to _write_ to your database? That sounds very dangerous.

Comment: I meant anybody could run strings on the *application*.  E.g. anybody could reverse-engineer the app and find out what its login credentials are.  So I want to limit that login to only those operations necessary for its functioning.

Comment: Oh, right, I see your point.  Yes, anybody with the app can obtain write access to the database.  They could theoretically write bogus records to it.  I don't see any way around that problem, but for now I can live with it.

Comment: you realize that somebody could just do `UPDATE grades SET status=NULL` and all records in your database would be ruined. You _so_ need to create an API that your application can query.

Comment: *Sigh*, you're right.  Back to the drawing board.  Looks like stored procedure is the way to go.  Or write a front end on the server.

Comment: As I mention in my answer below, the correct approach would be to create an API that your users communicate with your database through.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a peculiar way to protect a table.  It might make sense in some cases, though usually you want to provide some window of visibility so users are not blind to their effects on data.

To completely implement a write-only database, use stored procedures.  The procedures can have full access to the database, and users can be granted access only to stored procedures.

Comment: I think this is the best answer.  Learning how to write stored procedures now.

Comment: Well, this worked pretty well, although an attacker could still corrupt the database by guessing recno values. I've come up with a security protocol to protect against that.  Thanks for everybody's help.

Answer (score 3):

Oooh!  I've got it.  I'll give my user SELECT privilege for just the recno column.

Leaving the question open though, just in case someone comes up with a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `VIEW` and grant the user full access to it. This view should only contain the rows which that you want the user to be able to edit.

A different, and possibly more suitable approach, would be to completely abstract this mechanism away from the DBMS and instead create an API that you allow your users to query.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily achieved by granting the correct level of access:

```
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE GRADES FROM USER1; -- to clear out all privileges
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLE GRADES TO USER1;
```

This will allow USER1 to insert, update and delete, but not select, from the grades table.

Change `USER1` to `PUBLIC` or some group or whatever as you need.
Change the permissions list as you need.

Your situation is a version of a classic example in an IBM database course I used to teach:
Financial staff are allowed to give a % pay rise, but not to *see* what the pay level is, for employees, so

```
GRANT UPDATE ON TABLE EMPLOYEE TO ACCT_STAFF; -- an no other privileges
```

Which allows them to give a 15% pay rise by executing:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET PAY = PAY * 1.15 WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 666;
```

Comment: This is essentially what I've already done, but the "WHERE recno=123" clause requires SELECT privilege.  E.g. "ERROR 1143 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'ACCT_STAFF' for column 'EMPLOYEE_ID' in table 'EMPLOYEE'

Comment: @EdwardFalk You are allowed to use `WHERE recno=123` in an update statement *without* having select access to the table. I don't understand what you are talking about.

Comment: I just tried under 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10 using the exact commands you gave and got this error: "ERROR 1143 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'ACCT_STAFF'@'foo.com' for column 'EMPLOYEE_ID' in table 'EMPLOYEE'".  Maybe more recent versions of the server allow this.  I certainly agree that it *should* have worked, but it didn't.

Comment: Same here with `10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1`, and `UPDATE` with a `WHERE` requires `SELECT` permission too.