# Node.js MySQL - why does UPDATE statement also run SELECT, how can I avoid this for a write-only MySQL user

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using Node.js with a MySQL database.

I only need my Node script to write to the database, so I've created a write-only user with permissions only to perform `INSERT` and `UPDATE` on a single table.

However, when running the simple script below, I receive an error:

```
ER_COLUMNACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: SELECT command denied to user 'write_only_user'@'localhost' for column 'id' in table 'table'
```

My test code is as follows

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "write_only_user",
    password: "*******",
    database:'*******',
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");

    var sql = "INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (1)";

    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Result: " + result);
        //console.log(result.insertId);

        var sql = "UPDATE table SET column = 2 WHERE id = " + result.insertId;

        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err; // Error thrown here
            console.log("Result: " + result);
        });
    });
});
```

I assume the `mysql` package performs a `SELECT` after the `UPDATE` to return the new record.

Ignoring the error doesn't work - the `UPDATE` doesn't seem to run at all.

Is there any way to avoid this additional `SELECT`?

- Node v9.8.0
- MySQL 5.7.21
- Node.js `mysql` 2.15.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried running the same query from the same user a different way? Does it only error in the `mysql` package?

Comment: There's some good info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828139/how-can-i-update-a-specific-record-without-select-permission

Comment: Yep, thanks all - testing on MySQL command line with the write-only user I get the same error, so it's not the node package. The linked SO post is helpful.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. That's interesting - I never knew it needed that permission.